# How to place boundaries on the area a sprite can be drawn on an LCD

Tags: c, random, lcd, teensy

I'm working on a microprocessor with an LCD screen, and i'm writing code which randomly displays some sprites.

```
void setup_sprite() {

Sprite sprite[8];
Sprite * sprite_pointer = &sprite;
byte sprite_bitmap [] = {
BYTE( 10100000 ),
BYTE( 01000000 ),
BYTE( 10100000 )
};
const int width = 3;
const int height = 3;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    init_sprite(&sprite, rand()%82, rand()%43, 3, 3, sprite_bitmap);//83/43 is the LCD screen dimensions
    draw_sprite(&sprite);
    refresh();
    }
return 0;
}
```

How would I go about placing boundaries on where it can be drawn? it should only be drawn within a specific area on the screen. I was thinking an if statement where if the sprite is drawn outside the boundary it redraws until  it's correct.

Specifically the problem is I have about 10 pixels in from the left side of the screen left for a menu, the sprites shouldn't be drawn in that area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since

```
rand() % 82
```

generates a random value between 0 and 81, you could modify that to

```
10 + rand() % 72
```

to generate a random value between 10 and 81 instead, which I believe is what you want for your x coordinate.

Comment: Perfect, so much simpler than my theory.